# How can i store characters like /xfe\xff\x8bE\xfc\x8b\xdf\x8b}\ in a variable -Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, binary

I heard that you can't merge to .exe files to gether so I thought what will happen if i stored the executable app as binary inside my app and then built it.

In python I did it:

```
myappBinary = 
with open("sample.exe", 'wb') as outf:
    outf.write(b'''3\xb4\xcb^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0\x00\x''') # for example
```

but in Vb.net I can't even store the binary data, any help?
I tried:

```
Dim content() As Byte = <![CDATA[3\xb4\xcb^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0\x00\x]]>.Value
```

And I tried to call the cmd to run `echo BINARYDATA > sample.exe` and it's not working
Then I tried:

```
Dim content As Byte = "3\xb4\xcb^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0\x00\x"
```

every time it shows me this msg `Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'Byte()'` or something realted to it

THE PROBLEM WILL SOLVED IF I CAN STORE A BINARIES DATA AND WRITE THEM.
I know that i can simply read an .exe file using  `Dim data2() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes("myApp.exe")` but i want to store the data in a variable.

Any help?

Comment: You can add a File to a Project's Resources. It will be stored as a byte array. Users may receive anti-virus alerts. Your executable will be quarantined in this case.

Comment: sounds good idea, but then how can i reach it. I'm sorry I'm new in this thing

Comment: `File.WriteAllBytes("[The File Path]", My.Resources.TheResourceFileName)`